# Hostinger responsive template wont load. I have been trying for two days and it wont go past the importing content section

Tags: wordpress, web, responsive, builder

I attempt to import a responsive starter template that is only one page to build a website.  It initiates and get stuck spinning a green wheel and never progresses past it.  Hosting customer service has no idea what to do and recommended here.

Retried multiple times.  Hostinger "boosted" my account. I have cleared my cache.

Comment: I have tried multiple browsers.